# What happens when a spark dataframe is converted to Pandas dataframe using toPandas() method

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe which i can convert to pandas dataframe using the

```
toPandas()
```

method available in pyspark.

I have the following queries regarding this?

1. Does this conversion break the purpose of using spark
   itself(Distributed computing)?
2. The dataset is going to be huge , so what about the speed and memory
   issues?
3. If  somebody can also explain ,what exactly happens with this one
   line of code,that would really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yes, once `toPandas` is called on spark-dataframe it will get out of distributed system and new pandas dataframe will be in driver node of cluster.

And if the spark-data frame is huge and if doesnt fit into driver memory it will crash.